# How would one prevent a specific animation from running after an unrelated button is clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an excellent lightweight jquery slider I've stumbled upon called Easyfader, which can be viewed here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rAzxI

The slider works wonders, however I need to add a video component to the slider. I was successful in adding an iframe with the class "slide" however the slider continues to move as expected to the succeeding slides even if the user has pressed play on the youtube iframe.

Ideally we would like the slider to stop it's default timed animation and only allow a slide change upon a user clicking a slider navigation arrow or menu.

Below I attempt to create a function which is fired upon click of the youtube video, the problem is that I cannot successfully pause the default transition animation. I tried to kill the function all together which is also not ideal nor did it work.

Please refer to the link provided above detailing the code which is in use and see below where I have made an attempt but have indeed failed.

```
function videoPlaying()
{
  $('#video-still').fadeOut(1000);
  var theURL = $('.embed-video').attr('src');
  $('.embed-video').attr('src', theURL + '?fs=1&amp;feature=oembed&amp;&autoplay=1');
  ('.slide').stop(true, true);
}
```

Comment: $("#your_button_id").click(function() { $('#video-still').stop(); } ); should work.

Comment: #video-still is an arbitrary image placeholder which requires no interaction to accomplish what it is exactly I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the plugin a bit to respond to `pause` events, by clearing the timer

add

```
$container.on('pause.easyFader', function(){clearTimeout(slideTimer);});
```

in the plugin in the `init` method..

And now you can call

```
$('#Fader').trigger('pause.easyFader');
```

from wherever you want to pause the slideshow.. it will resume once you click on any of the next/previous (or paging) buttons..

Demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/jzfJq

Comment: well done. This is exactly what I needed. It even returns to normal flow upon clicking the arrows or buttons after the movie has finished! Thank you!